# How to show date's day part with a leading zero in Git log with --date=local?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-log

I currently use:

```
git log --pretty='format:%ad %Cgreen%h%Cred%d %Creset%s' --date=local
```

which produces:

```
Tue Apr 2 16:02:24 2013 b8b3975 Debug info for hidHandle.isClosed added.
Mon Apr 1 15:31:46 2013 6b9b1ca Fixed mouse-button-up event images.
Mon Apr 1 13:23:26 2013 907e8c6 Improved code-behind formatting.
Thu Mar 28 17:14:59 2013 d2edade Remember colors on redraw.
Thu Mar 28 16:49:51 2013 7491a07 Seven colors in a row.
```

I desire for this:

```
Tue Apr 02 16:02:24 2013 b8b3975 Debug info for hidHandle.isClosed added.
Mon Apr 01 15:31:46 2013 6b9b1ca Fixed mouse-button-up event images.
Mon Apr 01 13:23:26 2013 907e8c6 Improved code-behind formatting.
Thu Mar 28 17:14:59 2013 d2edade Remember colors on redraw.
Thu Mar 28 16:49:51 2013 7491a07 Seven colors in a row.
```

Results using `--date=relative`, `--date=iso`, `--date=rfc` and `--date=default` were not satisfactory.

Am I missing any other option? I am using `git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1` on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a quick look at the sourcecode and what you desire is not possible. You only get that one format if you want timezone-adjusted times. If it’s important to you, you could pass the output through `sed`:

```
git log --pretty='format:%ad %Cgreen%h%Cred%d %Creset%s' --date=local | sed 's/^\(.\{7\}\) \([0-9]\) /\1 0\2 /'
```

If you want to set this up as an alias `mylog`, run this command:

```
git config --global alias.mylog '!'"git log --pretty='format:%ad %Cgreen%h%Cred%d %Creset%s' --date=local | sed 's/^\(.\{7\}\) \([0-9]\) /\1 0\2 /'"
```

Or add this to your `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
        mylog = !git log --pretty='format:%ad %Cgreen%h%Cred%d %Creset%s' --date=local | sed 's/^\\(.\\{7\\}\\) \\([0-9]\\) /\\1 0\\2 /'
```

Comment: Your solution gives me exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to somehow incorporate what `sed` does, into a git alias? Not a big need, just curious. I avoided `sed` for a long time. Time to get acquainted now. I `sed` Hi!

Comment: Extenden my answer with infos for a git alias.

Comment: I noticed one thing with `sed` is that it doesn't add a new line at the end, so the bash prompt after the output continues on the same line.

Comment: I don’t have that problem and can’t reproduce it, but you can try adding a `&& echo` at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for following up with my questions. With `&& echo` at the end, it works perfectly now.